# Python Ctypes Exception: access violation reading

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I try to communicate with a PLC through a DLL (C API interface distributed by the manufacturer of the PLC). I'm using Python 3.1 who is embedded as a scripting environment in a other software (x64 - Windows 7).

I managed to get a few DLL functions working, but now a get an "Access violation reading" that I can't solve.

Information about the DLL function:

```
LONG AdsSyncReadReq(
  PAmsAddr  pAddr,
  ULONG     nIndexGroup,
  ULONG     nIndexOffset,
  ULONG     nLength,
  PVOID     pData
);
```

Parameters:

- pAddr: [in] Structure with NetId and port number of the ADS server.
- nIndexGroup: [in] Index Group.
- nIndexOffset: [in] Index Offset.
- nLength:[in] Length of the data in bytes.
- pData: [out] Pointer to a data buffer that will receive the data.
- Return value: Returns the function's error status.

Structure AmsAddr:

```
typedef struct {
  AmsNetId        netId;
  USHORT          port;
} AmsAddr, *PAmsAddr;
```

Structure AmsNetId

```
typedef struct {
  UCHAR        b[6];
} AmsNetId, *PAmsNetId;
```

Python Implementation:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from ctypes import *

#I've tried OleDll and windll as wel..
ADS_DLL = CDLL("C:/Program Files/TwinCAT/Ads Api/TcAdsDll/x64/TcAdsDll.dll")

class AmsNetId(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('NetId',  c_ubyte*6)]

class AmsAddr(Structure):
    _fields_=[('AmsNetId',AmsNetId),('port',c_ushort)]

# DLL function working fine
version = ADS_DLL.AdsGetDllVersion()
print(version)

#DLL function working fine
errCode = ADS_DLL.AdsPortOpen()
print(errCode)

#DLL function using the AmsAddr() class, working fine
amsAddress = AmsAddr()
pointer_amsAddress = pointer(amsAddress)
errCode = ADS_DLL.AdsGetLocalAddress(pointer_amsAddress)
print(errCode)
contents_amsAddres = pointer_amsAddress.contents

#Function that doens't work:
errCode = ADS_DLL.AdsSyncReadReq()
print(errCode) # --> errCode = timeout error, normal because I didn't pass any arguments

# Now with arguments:
plcNetId = AmsNetId((c_ubyte*6)(5,18,18,27,1,1)) #correct adress to the PLC
plcAddress = AmsAddr(plcNetId,801) #correct port to the PLC
nIndexGroup = c_ulong(0xF020)
nIndexOffset = c_ulong(0x0) 
nLength = c_ulong(0x4)
data = c_void_p()
pointer_data = pointer(data)

#I tried with an without the following 2 lines, doesn't matters 
ADS_DLL.AdsSyncReadReq.argtypes=[AmsAddr,c_ulong,c_ulong,c_ulong,POINTER(c_void_p)]
ADS_DLL.AdsSyncReadReq.restype=None

#This line crashes
errCode = ADS_DLL.AdsSyncReadReq(plcAddress,nIndexGroup,nIndexOffset,nLength,pointer_data)
print(errCode)


>>>> Error in line 57: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

I hope anyone can't figure out what's wrong. I'm only a advanced novice in Python programming with no experience at all in C

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing invalid pointer, provide a valid memory buffer instead:

```
data = create_string_buffer(nLength)
```

The argument should be just `c_void_p` instead of `POINTER(c_void_p)` if `PVOID` means `void *`. Don't set restype to `None` (the function returns `LONG`).

Also pass `pointer(plcAddress)` (specify `POINTER(AmsAddr)` in argtypes).

Use correct calling convention (choose between cdll, windll, oledll).

Comment: I tried you solution but it didn't work. I still get the same error message. I guess the problem is in the first argument (plcAddress).

`errCode = ADS_DLL.AdsSyncReadReq(plcAddress)`

gives the same error

Comment: Thanks a lot. Error message is gone. I still don't have the response I want from the PLC but that something else.... :-)